# Two for loops in one function will not save an array after exiting for loop

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have two arrays I need to compare in a test.  I am testing a filter, it reads in an array of numbers and saves to `spareArray`. I then click on a filter button which is also the element the int list is listed in, `style`. I read in the list again and save it to the second array, `spareIntArray`. After the readin I send the arrays to two methods, one parses string to float and the second gets ride of '-' that are in my lists I do not want to compare.  However after the run of the second for loop reading in `spareIntArray` the array is set to undefined. I tested that the array is filled with elements by doing a log and it seems to be.  I am quite confused what is happening here.

```js
/**
 * Created by nphillips on 8/11/2015.
 */

var helper = require('./../pages/helper-page.js');
var capacityPage = module.exports = {

  variables: {
    //the theaterStyle element list
    theaterStyle: element.all(by.css("[data-style='theater']")),
  },

  readsInTheater: function() {
    capacityPage.readsIn(capacityPage.variables.theaterStyle);
  },

  removesDashes: function(style, array) {
    while (array.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
      array.splice(array.indexOf('-'), 1);
    };
    console.log(array + "count ");
    return array;
  },

  readsIn: function(style) {
    var spareArray = [];
    var spareIntArray = [];
    style.count().then(function(count) {
      console.log(count);
      j = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //scrolls down the list element by element
        browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", style.get(i).getWebElement());
        style.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
          spareArray[j] = text;
          console.log(text, spareArray[j], j);
          expect(text).toEqual(spareArray[j++]);
        });
      }
    }).then(function() {
      // style.click()
      browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", style.get(0).getWebElement());
      style.count().then(function(count) {
        console.log(count);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          //scrolls down the list element by element
          browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", style.get(i).getWebElement());
          style.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
            spareIntArray[j] = text;
            console.log(text, spareIntArray[j], j + "frawer");
            expect(text).toEqual(spareIntArray[j++]);
          });
        };

      });
      spareArray = capacityPage.stringToFloatArray(spareArray);
      spareIntArray = capacityPage.stringToFloatArray(spareIntArray);
      capacityPage.removesDashes(style, spareArray);
      capacityPage.removesDashes(style, spareIntArray);
      expect(spareArray).toEqual(spareIntArray);
    });
  },

  stringToFloatArray: function(array) {
    function int_arr(a, b) {
      return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
    }

    array = array.sort(int_arr);
    console.log(array + "float");
    return array;
  },


};
```

Answer (score 1):

Is spareIntArray being undefined?. It could be because you are calling stringToFloatArray on spareIntArray before it is filled. I think that your check should be inside the promise callback. However I am a bit concerned on why you are using asynchronous data retrieval on the document. Is there a way to do it in a synchronous way? Soemething like

```
style.count().then(function(count) {
  console.log(count);

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    //scrolls down the list element by element
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", style.get(i).getWebElement());

    var text = style.get(i).getText();
    spareArray.push(text);
    console.log(text, spareArray[i], i);
    expect(text).toEqual(spareArray[i]);
    });
  }
}).then(function() {
  // style.click()
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", style.get(0).getWebElement());
  style.count().then(function(count) {
    console.log(count);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      //scrolls down the list element by element
      browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", style.get(i).getWebElement());

      var text = style.get(i);
      spareIntArray.push(text);
      console.log(text, spareIntArray[i], i + "frawer");
      expect(text).toEqual(spareIntArray[i]);
    };

  spareArray = capacityPage.stringToFloatArray(spareArray);
  spareIntArray = capacityPage.stringToFloatArray(spareIntArray);
  capacityPage.removesDashes(style, spareArray);
  capacityPage.removesDashes(style, spareIntArray);
  expect(spareArray).toEqual(spareIntArray);
  });
});
```

},

Comment: I just tried the code you provided and I got some crazy result and the process became out of memory.  It is automation testing being done on a non angular page, I'm not sure if that answers your question.  The array of spareIntArray shows up as undefined after it exits the for loop.  I'm not great at promises, I'm still trying to catch the hang of it.  From what I'm seeing is the promise is resolving in the for loop and is not passing the array through.

Comment: Sorry I did not test the code, Be aware that it is just psuedo code since I modified the style.get(i).getText() to be sycnhronous. At first test simply moving the your checks inside the promise. Just be aware that the promise resolves at an undefined time, so if your code starts analysing the result of the promise before it is resolved, you might get unexpected behavior.

Comment: is there a way to not resolve the promise?  At the top I do a read in from a for loop and though out the function the spareArray is usable. I'm confused on why the behaviors are different. I moved the string to floats and dash removal method code out of the for loop and it still shows spareIntArray as an empty loop however spareArray is filled.

Comment: Your string to floats has to be out of the for loop just below the second for loop (But not inside!). That is correct, what I am concerned is more about "style.get(i).getText().then(function(text) ". Is there a way to remove the promise and just get the Text straight away?

Comment: I will give that a shot and let you know how it goes

Comment: I also see another problem, the counter "j" has to be reset before you start the second loop, or it will start writing from a random position. Is there a reason why you are using j instead of i? They both seem to work at the same pace.